# check if the person have pervious record with certain date :db2 sql

Tags: sql, database, db2

i have the following table :

```
id      name        start        end 
1       Asla      2021-01-01   2021-12-31
1       Asla      2022-01-01   2022-04-15
2       Tina      2021-05-16   2021-09-23
3       Layla     2021-01-01   2021-09-27
3       Layla     2022-01-01   2022-07-18
2       Sim       2020-05-12   2020-08-13
3       Anderas   2021-07-01   2021-09-13
3       Anderas   2021-10-01   2021-11-18
3       Anderas   2022-01-01   2029-11-18
4       Klara     2022-01-01     null
```

what i want to do  get persons that have work (date) under 2021 and  create a new column that show status (if the person continue having work under 2022 -- ok else not ok  and if the person is new like 'Klara' get new  ) and show last record for every person . maybe too End = null ??????
i tried this  .

````
select w.id ,w.name ,w.start ,w.end, max_date.end 
      from Work_date w
left join (select * from Work_date  where start>='2022-01-01')max_date on max_date.id=id  
     where w.start>='2021-01-01'
``` but the problem i get the result as this 
<pre>
id      name          start        end 
1       Asla         2021-01-01   null
1       Asla         2022-01-01   2022-04-15
2       Tina         2021-05-16   null
3       Layla        2021-01-01   null
3       Layla        2022-01-01   2022-07-18
3       Anderas      2021-07-01   null
3       Anderas      2021-10-01   2021-11-18
3       Anderas      2022-01-01   null
4       Klara        2022-01-01   null
</pre>
men i want to get result as <pre>
id      name        start        end           status
1       Asla       2022-01-01   2022-04-15      ok 
2       Tina       2021-05-16   2021-09-23      not ok
3       Layla      2022-01-01   2022-07-18      ok
3       Anderas    2022-01-01   2029-11-18      ok
4       Klara      2022-01-01     null          ok
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can simply aggregate.
Then use a `CASE WHEN` for the status.

> ```
> select 
>   w.id 
> , w.name
> , max(w.start) as start
> , max(w.end) as end
> , case
>   when year(max(end)) < 2022 then 'not ok'
>   else 'ok'
>   end as status
> from Work_date w
> where w.start >= '2021-01-01'
> group by w.id, w.name
> order by w.id, max(w.start), max(w.end);
> ```

| ID | NAME | START | END | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Asla | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-15 | ok |
| 2 | Tina | 2021-05-16 | 2021-09-23 | not ok |
| 3 | Layla | 2022-01-01 | 2022-07-18 | ok |
| 3 | Anderas | 2022-01-01 | 2029-11-18 | ok |
| 4 | Klara | 2022-01-01 | *null* | ok |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=3e2010e5339bb43ad62758e49818533f)*